# Import firebase analytics data into BigQuery for some specific events only

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

We have 100+ events (activities performed by users) for our android application, out of which we only want to track 10-15 events data. Remaining events are not important from analytics point of view.
Can I extract specific events only from Firebase to BigQuery in the app_events table?

I understand that I can query out required events after all the events are dumped into BigQuery. This may not be the optimal solution as I don't want to process GBs of data every 10-15 minutes(intraday table). Can specific events be extracted from Firebase analytics data? Or is there a better way to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are multiple options how this can be addressed. You cannot control the granularity of data that gets exported automatically. So you need to accept all events will be exported.

1. Keep a copy of interested events only.

What you can do is either leave the original data as is, and copy and maintain a duplicate of the data only that you are interested in, and build your queries on the copy table. This way costs will be lower as you will query only a table that holds your important data.

2. Delete data you don't need

You can even with [DML delete all](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax) events you are not interested. That's a simple DELETE dml call. But please know that you won't get data back, so maybe you want first to export, which is free and keep archived the file. Cold storage is cheap.

Comment: Even for duplicating data for required events, i'll have to query the intraday table again and again, because the data is required in real time. 
Ex: If intraday table size is 15GB, and I query it 48 times a day, the amount of data processed would be **720 GBs** everyday.
Is this a viable solution?

Also, DML won't be possible as we are using legacy SQL format in BigQuery.

Comment: DML works, and its not being affected by legacy/or standard. Simply you can run and delete old data. Are you aware that 1TB query costs only $5? I don't know what is your buget but I see it's an affordable amount around $110 per month for you.